# R save function using placeholder names

Tags: r

I have several scripts that need to be run repeatedly. In each, a series of steps are performed, resulting in three dataframe objects that need to be saved with unique names for each execution of the script. Within the script, I want to call a save() function call in which there are placeholder names for the dataframe object/dataframe filename but I want to specify the actual values for those placeholder names outside of script.

```
# inside "Script.R":
# series of steps to generate three dataframes (create fake DFs here)
path0 <- "C:/Data/"
DF1 <- data.frame(a=seq(1,16,by=2), b=LETTERS[1:8], c=sample(10:20,8,replace=TRUE))
DF2 <- data.frame(a=seq(1,16,by=2), b=LETTERS[1:8], c=sample(10:20,8,replace=TRUE))
DF3 <- data.frame(a=seq(1,16,by=2), b=LETTERS[1:8], c=sample(10:20,8,replace=TRUE))
save(DF1 , file=paste0(path0,"DF1", ".rda")) 
save(DF2 , file=paste0(path0,"DF2", ".rda")) 
save(DF3 , file=paste0(path0,"DF3", ".rda"))
```

Then, I'd like to call the script from source, but specify the desired object and filenames to replace the placeholder names generated in the script, such as:

```
DF1 <- RealDF1objectname 
DF2 <- RealDF2objectname 
DF3 <- RealDF13bjectname 
source("Script1.R")
```

I'm thinking the assign() function may be useful here, but I am not sure how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `function` lets call it `script` and pass it desired object and filenames:

```
script<- function (n1,n2,n3) {
#
path0 <-  path0 <- "C:/Data/"
DF1 <- data.frame(a=seq(1,16,by=2), b=LETTERS[1:8], c=sample(10:20,8,replace=TRUE))
DF2 <- data.frame(a=seq(1,16,by=2), b=LETTERS[1:8], c=sample(10:20,8,replace=TRUE))
DF3 <- data.frame(a=seq(1,16,by=2), b=LETTERS[1:8], c=sample(10:20,8,replace=TRUE))
#
save(DF1 , file=paste0(path0, n1, ".rda")) 
save(DF2 , file=paste0(path0, n2, ".rda")) 
save(DF3 , file=paste0(path0, n3, ".rda")) 
}
```

> Use

```
source('~/script.R')
script("temp1","temp2","temp3")
```

> Output

```
> list.files(path0)
[1] "script.R"  "temp1.rda" "temp2.rda" "temp3.rda"
```